# sed: print directory tree with time and ls -altr info

Tags: linux, sed, command-line, printing

The following prints the directory structure of the current location, which is what I want. However, since I'm using the find command, there are no additional meta info such as time, size, etc.

Is there a way for me to list the ls -altr info alongside each name? I mainly care about the size, date, and time fields of ls -altr.

```
find . | sed -e "s/[^-][^\/]*\// |/g" -e "s/|\([^ ]\)/|-\1/"
.
 |-one
 |-two
 | |-two_2
 | |-two_1
 |-test_file
```

For example:

```
 |-one 4096 Mar  6 16:37
```

Comment: `tree -s -D` ... not sed, but close to what you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks, but this is on a small embedded system and I don't have the tree command @tink

Comment: ` ls -l $(which tree)
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 85664 Oct 26  2014 /usr/bin/tree` ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to Cyrus's deleted answer. The problem with it was that the date format returned by `%Ax` contains slashes.

```
find . -printf "%p (%s, %Tb %Td %TY %TH:%TM)\n" |
  sed -E 's,[^/]+/,|-,g; s,^\|,-|,; s,-\|, |,g'
```

Comment: Yeah I realized that too. Thank you!

Comment: My version of 'find' doesn't have the -printf option, only -print0. Do you know how I can make this work?

Comment: Read your `stat` man page: can you get the same information using stat?

Comment: What's your OS? What's your version of find? I wonder about your use of the [tag:linux] tag.